# Kotlin : How to update a value of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to update at any time some values in my RecyclerView.

Here is my data class ParameterText:

```
data class ParameterText(
    var parameterName: String?,
    var parameterValue: String?
)
```

Here is my ViewHolder class ParameterTextViewHolder:

```
class ParameterTextViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val parameterName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterName)
    val parameterText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterValue)
}
```

Here is my Adapter (in my Activity):

```
// Adapter
private val parametersTextFoundList = emptyDataSourceTyped<ParameterText>()
```

And here is my RecyclerView setup (also in my Activity):

```
rv_parameters_text.setup {
    withDataSource(parametersTextFoundList)
    withItem<ParameterText, ParameterTextViewHolder>(R.layout.parameter_text) {
        onBind(::ParameterTextViewHolder) { _, item ->
            parameterName.text = item.parameterName
            parameterText.text = item.parameterValue
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
private fun updateValue(index: Int, value: String) {
    parametersTextFoundList[index].parameterValue = value
}
```

But it doesn't work. I read that I should also use the notifyDataSetChanged() method but I don't know where to use it. Can you help me?

Comment: always use the notifyDataSetChanged() method right after u set the values, so after this line 
parameterText.text = item.parameterValue

Comment: Ok but when I use that method where you told me, I get "Unresolved reference: notifyDataSetChanged". So what object do I need to use for this to work?

Comment: u call that for the recyclerview itself so like this
rv_parameters_text.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Ok I get it! Thanks a lot, it works! I edited my post with the answer.

Comment: it's better to write a new answer and mark it as the solution, or i can do the same and u mark it, for others to see it easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an entire suite of notify API's, including `notifyItemInserted()`, `notifyItemRemoved()`, `notifyItemChanged()`, which are designed to more efficiently update a `RecyclerView`.

when changing the contents of one existing row in your RecyclerView, its more efficient to use `adapter.notifyItemChanged(row)`, as `notifyDataSetChanged()` will reload the entire RecyclerView.  I recommend:

```
private fun updateValue(index: Int, value: String) 
{
    parametersTextFoundList[index].parameterValue = value
    rv_parameters_text.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(index)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer? How can I update an item of my adapter if my adapter is of type Any?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use notifyDataSetChanged() method with the update like this

```
rv_parameters_text.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
```